# Are there any javascript engine differences between iOS 4 -> iOS 5/6 that would cause this error in this snippet of code?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I've ran into a javascript error here at work (it happens on iOS 4.2/4.3 tested on the simulator)
The javascript debug console at the safari simulator shows this error message:

SyntaxError: Parse error - line 43

Here's the code from line 42-43

```
line 42: args[0] = obj[methodName].bind(obj); 
line 43: jobQueue.do.apply(jobQueue, args);
```

The 'do' function applied to the jobQueue object is an inner function and does nothing special besides slicing and array and pushing some elements into another array.

```
do: function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        this.pendingJobs.push(args);
        scheduleJobProcessing.call(this);
    }
```

I suspect that the problem is the 'apply' function, which is weird since the parameters are correct (the second parameter is always an array as demanded here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)).
So...since it's a problem we've only detect in iOS 4, is there any javascript engine differences between iOS 4 -> iOS 5/6 that would cause a problem in that snippet of code? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You wouldn't be getting a "Syntax error" if `apply` were not available or if there were something specifically wrong with `apply`

Comment: Is it complaining about the `do`? Try changing that `do` to some other word. [eg `run`]

Comment: The debugger in Safari does not give me a lot of info...only that SyntaxError: Parse error - line 43, I'll try to change the name of the function to see it helps

Comment: Changing the name of the function did it, i hate when this happens hehe...Answer the question so i can give you your very deserved points